# Scala: Triple Context Bounds, evidence parameters not found

Tags: scala, context-bound

I have edited this to a simpler form of the question to which @Zhi Yuan Wang responded :

```
object ContBound { 
  def f2[A: Seq, B: Seq]: Unit = {
      val a1: Seq[A] = evidence$1
      val b2: Seq[B] = evidence$2 
     }

  def f3[A: Seq, B: Seq, C: Seq]: Unit = {
    val a1: Seq[A] = evidence$1
    val b2: Seq[B] = evidence$2
    val a3: Seq[C] = evidence$3      
  }   
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
not found value evidence$1
not found value evidence$2
type mismatch; found :Seq[A] required: Seq[C]
```

despite getting the following in the REPL:

```
 def f3[A: Seq, B: Seq, C: Seq]: Unit =
 |    {
 |       val a1: Seq[A] = evidence$1
 |       val b2: Seq[B] = evidence$2
 |       val a3: Seq[C] = evidence$3      
 |    }  
f3: [A, B, C](implicit evidence$1: Seq[A], implicit evidence$2: Seq[B], implicit evidence$3: Seq[C])Unit
```

Zhi's awnser is correct. The following compiles:

```
object ContBound { 
  def f2[A: Seq, B: Seq]: Unit = {
    val a1: Seq[A] = evidence$1
    val b2: Seq[B] = evidence$2 
  }

  def f3[A: Seq, B: Seq, C: Seq]: Unit = {
    val a1: Seq[A] = evidence$3
    val b2: Seq[B] = evidence$4
    val a3: Seq[C] = evidence$5      
  }   
}
```

However I still don't see this as correct behaviour, as these are parameters for two different methods and methods are normally allowed to reuse parameter names.

Comment: you might try looking at the output of `scalac -print`, or at the generated bytecode

Comment: Your notion of "correct" is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
def comma3[A: RParse, B: RParse, C: RParse, D](f: (A, B, C) => D): D =
    expr match {
       case CommaExpr(Seq(e1, e2, e3)) =>
           f(evidence$3.get(e1), evidence$4.get(e2), evidence$5.get(e3))
}
```

since the the evidence$1 already used by

```
def comma3[]??
```

Comment: Already used by `comma2`, you mean.  And yes, this is it.  And also shows why you should never, ever rely upon the compiler-generated numbering of hidden parameters.